# Different sizes for /var/lib/docker

Tags: linux, docker

I don't know actually if this is more a "classic" linux or a docker question but:

On an VM where some of my docker containers are running I've a strange thing. /var/lib/docker is an own partition with 20GB formatted with ext4. When I look over the partition with df -h I see this:

```
eti-gwl1v-dockerapp1 root# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.8G  815M  7.0G  11% /run
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2        12G  3.2G  8.0G  29% /
/dev/sda7       3.9G   17M  3.7G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda5       7.8G  6.8G  649M  92% /var
/dev/sdb2        20G   47M   19G   1% /usr2
/dev/sdb1        20G  2.9G   16G  16% /var/lib/docker
```

So usage is at 16%. But when I now navigate to /var/lib and do a du -sch docker I see this:

```
eti-gwl1v-dockerapp1 root# cd /var/lib
eti-gwl1v-dockerapp1 root# du -sch docker
19G     docker
19G     total
eti-gwl1v-dockerapp1 root#
```

So same directory/partition but two sizes? How is that going?

Comment: Is it possible that sparse files are involved?

Comment: How do you mean? Invisible files?

Comment: I mean [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). On many file-systems, files can be given a "maximum" logical size while they actually consume less physical space on the storage medium.